# Laravel 5.3-5.4 The Difference between $request->user(); and Auth::user();

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was reviewing some of the code logic on my system and wondered about some things. After a person has logged onto the system you can either use `$request->user();` or `Auth::user();` to get the user object.

**My questions are:**

1. What are the key differences between the two other than the obvious ones?
2. Is the user being pulled from the database in both cases or is one pulling the user object from some stored cache?
3. Are both cases leveraging passport's functionality to get the user from the database? or is it being pulled from a mystical storage land that is difficult to find?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers!

Comment: They're effectively the same. If you don't like Laravel Facades you'd go for the method off Request. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user

Comment: While this is a good response and is appreciated, I'm still confused about how they're hitting the database. Are both Hitting the database or is the user being pulled from something stored in cache server-side?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a brief description:

`Auth::user();` holds the credentials or you can say the information when a user logs into application using `Auth`.

When the user is logged successfully, it's credentials are stored in the form of `cookies` or `sessions` that are destroyed after logout.

No it is not pulled from database. The logged in user details are stored in `session` and pulled from there.

Comment: If you want more information just comment down and I will update the answer accordingly.